# Match string with Exactly 2 of a given character? (e.g. 2 literal periods)

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with a regex to match on any string that has exactly 2 periods?

This **should** match: 12.3.2 Fusion
This **should not** match: 12.3.2.1 Fusion.

I know this is failrly easy i'm sure.  Just not too familiar with regex yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be:

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$
```

Explanation:

- `^` and `$` are "start of string" and "end of string"; here, they ensure that you're matching the *entire* string.
- `[^abc]` means "any character that is not `a` or `b` or `c`"; so, `[^.]*` is a substring that does not contain any periods.
- `\.` means "a period". (Without the backslash, `.` means "any character except newline", which is not what you want.)

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*$/
```

Zero or more non-periods, a period, zero or more non-periods, a period, and zero or more non-periods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
 /^[^.]*(\.[^.]*){2}[^.]*$/
```

Comment: That will match a substring that contains exactly two periods, even if there are other periods elsewhere in the string, which is presumably not what the OP wants.